# SQL Query - Display competitors with same results in same event

Tags: sql

I am trying to select the Compeititors who got the same placing in the same event from a hypothetical table, 'Results'. Does anyone know what is wrong with this query?

I seem to only get the same competitior number next to each other not different competitor numbers.

```
Select Eventid, Place, c1.Competitornum, c2.Competitornum
From Results natural join Results c2
Where c1.Place = c2.Place 
and c1.Eventid = c2.Eventid
Order by Eventid, Place
```

Answer (score 0):

A `natural join` filters on all identical fields.  That means your current `where` clause is superfluous.  It also means the join condition includes `Compititornum`, explaining why you only get rows with identical `Competitornum`.

Instead of a `natural join`, try an `inner join`.  With an `inner join` you can set the join condition explicitly in the `on` clause:

```
select  c1.Eventid
,       c1.Place
,       c1.Competitornum
,       c2.Competitornum
from    Results c1
inner join 
        Results c2
on      c1.Place = c2.Place 
        and c1.Eventid = c2.Eventid
        and c1.Competitornum <> c2.Competitornum
```

Comment: Thanks so much for you help.  Reward 
A

Comment: You can "reward" answers by clicking the accept or upvote buttons to the left of the answer.